# Java: Controlling hardware tasks with pausable ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpoolexecutor

I want to implement a single-producer - multi-consumer logic where each consumer processing time depends on a hardware response.

**EDIT

I have a Set of objects (*devices*). Each object (*device*) corresponds to a hardware real unit I want to simulate in software.
My main class distributes a list of tasks to each device. Each task takes a certain time to complete - which I want to have control, in order to simulate the hardware operation. Each device object has its own `SingleThreadExecutorService` service executor to manage its own queued tasks. A `Sleep` on a task of a specific device object **should not** interfere on main, or other devices object's performance.

So far things are working but I am not sure how to get a future from the tasks without blocking the main thread with a while(!future.isDone()). When I do it, two problems occur:

- task 1 is submitted to `device[ 1 ].executor`. Tasks 1 sleeps to simulate hardware operation time.
- task 2 should be submitted to `device[ 2 ].executor` as soon as task 1 is submitted, but it won't, because main thread is hold `while` waiting for task 1 to return a `Future`. This issue accumulates delay on the simulation since every task added causes the next device to have to wait for the previous to complete, instead of running simultaneously.[image: delay propagation example]

Orange line indicates a command to force device to wait for 1000 milliseconds.
When Future returns, it then submits a new task to device 2, but it is already 1 second late, seen in blue line. And so on, green line shows the delay increment.

If I don't use Future to get when tasks were finished, the simulation seems to run correctly. I couldn't find a way to use future.isDone() without having to create a new thread just to check it. Also, I would really be glad if someone could advice me how to proceed in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to implement something where each consumer task is talking to a hardware device during the processing of its task, then the `run` method of the task should simply talk to the device and block until it receives the response from the device.  (How you do that will depend on the device and its API ...)

If your goal is to do the above with a *simulated* device (i.e. for testing purposes) then have the task call `Thread.sleep(...)` to simulate the time that the device would take to respond.

Based on your problem description (as I understand it), the `PausableSchedulerThreadPoolExecutor` class that you have found won't help.  What that class does is to pause the threads themselves.   All of them.

---

**UPDATE**

> task 2 should be submitted to device[ 2 ].executor as soon as task 1 is submitted, but it won't, *because main thread is hold while waiting for task 1 to return a `Future`*.

That is not correct.  The `Future` object is returned immediately ... when the task is submitted.

You mistake (probably) is that the main thread is calling `get` on the `Future`.  That will block.  But the point is that is your main thread *actually needs* to call `get` on the `Future` before submitting the next task then it is essentially single-threaded.

Real solution: figure out how to break that dependency that makes your application single threaded.  (But beware: if you pass the `Future` as a parameter to a task, then the corresponding worker thread may block.  Unless you have enough threads in the thread pool you could end up with starvation and reduced concurrency.)

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I am still a little confused about `Thread.sleep(...)` I thought this would cause the main thread to sleep, is itn't? My goal is to pause each `Runnable` object individually. I was debugging my code and noticed each runnable ( when sleeping ) was incrementing some delay to other threads. But that was because I was holding the main thread trapped in a while waiting for a `future.get()`. I think I need to edit my post in order to add some example.

Comment: That would be a good idea.  'Cos what you are saying doesn't make much sense to me.